# Kthread: Passing struct to function

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel, function-pointers

I'm trying to implement a kthread that needs to work with a thread.

I try to pass the struct like this which causes an error at compile time:

```
    int thread_function(void* data)
{
    killStruct obj = (killStruct) data;
    //msleep((unsigned int) time);
    printk(KERN_INFO"From the inner Thread: PID: %d, Time:%ld\n",obj->pid,obj->millisecondsToKill);
    //kill prozess by ID
    return 0;
}

static void prozess_kill(struct killStruct obj)
{
    task = kthread_run(&thread_function,(void*)obj ,obj->pid);
}
```

What is the correct way to pass a struct to such an function pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting the whole struct to a void pointer, which will not work.
You have to have pointer pointing to a valid struct and then pass that pointer, instead of a whole struct.

```
{
    struct killStruct* o = initializethestruct(); //malloc, set members

    prozess_kill( o ) ;
}

static void prozess_kill(struct killStruct* obj)
{
    task = kthread_run(&thread_function,(void*)obj ,obj->pid);
}


int thread_function(void* data)
{
    struct killStruct* obj = (struct killStruct*) data;
   ....
```

You also used the struct name in two different ways, it should be always `struct killStruct` or if it is a typedef then always `killStruct`.

Comment: This works but when for some strange reason the pid value of the obj struct is different inside the thread function. What could be wrong?

Comment: You are passing something other than obj struct.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the data pointer to a KillStruct * type, then dereference to obtain the Killstruct object.

```
 killStruct obj = *(killStruct *)data;
```